# Where can I research fifteenth century French and Italian coats of arms?

Tags: heraldry, nobility

I'm trying to track down coats of arms for the following people:

[Catherine of Taranto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_of_Taranto)

[Tristan de Clermont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan_de_Clermont)

But I don't know even where to start. Any ideas, even in general of where to look for fifteenth century French and Italian nobility?

Answer (score 7):

The [Catherine of Taranto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_of_Taranto) article you mention refers to the [Orsini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orsini_family) article, which shows the Orsini coat of arms:

[image: Orsini family coat of arms]

See the references and links at the bottom of the page.

Rely on the sources rather than Wikipedia in this case.

Update: This article on [François Guillaume de Castelnau de Clermont-Lodève](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Guillaume_de_Castelnau_de_Clermont-Lod%C3%A8ve), Archbishop of Narbonne, appears relevant. He was born in 1480, 50 years after Tristan's death; the central part of the coat of arms may not have changed. *But all this is supposition, included because you wanted leads.*

Note the [galero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galero) in the image:

[image: Coat of arms of François Guillaume de Castelnau de Clermont-Lodève]

Comment: Wouldn't every nobleman have his personal coat of arms, of course strongly related to the one of his family?

Answer (score 4):

The coat of arms of Guillem de Clermont-Lodève, ancestor of Tristan of Clermont, is described in *[Documens historiques et généalogiques sur les familles et les hommes remarquables du Rouergue](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_21YBAAAAQAAJ/page/538/mode/1up)* (Vol. 1, page 538) as "fascé d'or et de gueules de six pièces et un chef d'hermines". This coat of arms would have been inherited by Tristan, and is very similar to the one borne by the Archbishop of Narbonne referred to in andy256's answer. It omits the religious symbology, however, and the field is divided into six, rather than four.

A representation is available on the Wikipedia Commons:

[image]